# Find/Command Box doesn't work in Visual Studio 2012 - no change in current cursor position after pressing ENTER

Tags: visual-studio-2012, find, edit

I like to use the Find/Command Box to locate text in my current document.  I type a word or phrase and press enter and expect the editor to advance to the next line that contains this word or phrase.  Instead, when I press enter nothing happens.  If I press CTL+F3, all the matching words in the document are correctly highlighted.  If I choose find in current document, I see a list of all the lines containing the word or phrase.  But I can't get the Find/Command Box to work the way it used to work in previous versions of Visual Studio.  Is there an option I need to select?

Comment: I tend to use Ctrl+I to start an incremental search, rather than using the Find box.  Often you'll get to where you're going before needing to type the whole of the word you're looking for, plus the focus stays in the document so keys like Page Up and Page Down work without needing to hit Escape first to get out of the Find box.

Answer (score 0):

Which "find" option are you using ? You can get one by pressing CTRL+F and there is another one with the ctrl+shift+f.

You can press ctrl+F for the search box. You have to type there your word and then press enter to find next. You must remain in that search box while pressing enter. All the words are highlighted, but the current one is highlighted in a different color (by pressing enter you will move to the next)